# How to properly manage API call limits in a Python script?

Tags: python, time, sleep

I am writing a script that iterates over the elements of a list and for each one calls an api. Something like:

```
myList=['a','b',...] #200k items 

result_dict={}

for item in myList:
    result=myapi.myfunction(item) #I think this way is slower since it has to check credentials every iteration
    result_dict[item]=result
```

or, alternatively (maybe faster, I haven't checked)

```
myList=['a','b',...] #200k items 

result_dict={}

results=myapi.myfunction(myList) #I can pass either an item or a list

for id_, result in results:
     result_dict[id_]=result
```

I have a limit of 20.000 calls per day, after which I get billed for every extra request, and I am assuming that I will be able to fulfill all the 20k calls before the end of the day. Therefore, I need to think of some way to control it.

I thought about counting the calls made and, when I reach the 20k, I put the code on stand-by until the following midnight. Does it make sense? How can I implement it, for example through the `time.sleep()` function? I have no problem in leaving the script running, since I am working on an AWS remote server.

Can you suggest anything better?

Comment: Sounds like you have a lot of options you could try. Why not start with something simple and see if that works well? Like, you could time the average duration of a call and rate limit them with `sleep` in order to average out 20k requests over 24 hours. Or you could just send them as fast as possible and then stop when you hit the 24 hour limit, then keep looping and checking the number of calls in the past 24 hours, and start sending more once the number drops below 20k. Is there anything preventing you from trying those possible solutions?

Comment: @RandomDavis uhm, not sure I understand the last part of your comment. If I let it go for the 24 hrs I am most likely to exceed the 20k calls limit - and therefore be billed. Right?
There is nothing in particular preventing me from trying different approaches, but I strive for time since I'm on a tight deadline, so I was looking for something simple - not necessarily the best solution, but one I can implement fast.

Comment: I mean that you store the dates and times of all API calls, then only make more API calls if the number of API calls from the past 24 hours is below 20k. Unless it's reset at midnight instead of just a 24 hour period, in which case you'd wait until midnight instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options: spread the calls over the whole day (20000 / 24 calls per hour) or stop calling until midnight once you reach 20000 calls.

Just add a counter to the API calls, and a conditional to check wether you reached 20k calls or not.

If 20000 calls were reached, you can `time.sleep()` t seconds until midnight.

You can compute the number of seconds until midnight by using datetime:

```
import datetime
import time
now = datetime.datetime.now()
midnight = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
midnight = midnight.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0)
seconds_until_midnight = (midnight - now).total_seconds()
time.sleep(seconds_until_midnight)
```

Comment: Another option is to store the dates/times of all API calls, and check that in the past 24 hours, the total is less then 20k. That way the script won't arbitrarily wait until midnight, but instead will just make API calls whenever it can. That is, if the counter is reset dynamically, rather than arbitrarily at midnight.

Comment: Indeed @RandomDavis thats another solution, but we don't know if the limitation is per 24h or per natural day.

Comment: thanks guys! Indeed @RandomDavis solution is best, but I have to agree with AlanWik: I am not sure either about this, it's a RapidApi service and it says generically 20k/day, so I guess the midnight solution is safer (this is why I was asking for it in the first place).

Comment: thanks @AlanWik for pointing me out how to use the sleep function for my purpose! I'll try it out and mark your answer as accepted as soon as I check it

Comment: @AlanWik ok it works, just correct a couple of minor issues: it's "days=1" and midnight.replace() ;)